# Spring boot module bean returns incorrectly encoded string

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am a spring newbie.

I have a spring stand-alone application (MyModule) which is included as a module in another stand-alone application (MyMainApp) using the following annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {MyModule.class....}}
```

I have a bean that is in the MyModule application. This bean reads a file from Amazon S3 that contains a string with some German characters and returns it to an endpoint in MyMainApp. (I know this could have been a Service instead of a bean). This endpoint is annotated with -

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces =  "application/json charset=utf-8")
```

The issue:

When I run a Spring test in the MyModule application I get the correctly encoded (UTF-8) string.
[image]

(I also tried creating a similar endpoint in my MyModule Application and it returns the correct result.)

When I make a call to this bean method from my MyMainApp I get incorrectly encoded characters.

[image]

I read about CharacterEncodingFilter. Is that the right way to fix this?

Comment: what is the code that reads from s3? And also can you put System.out.println on the value read from S3 inside the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got solved when I -

1. Invalidated Intellij's cache
2. Upgraded to spring 2.3.0
3. Added

> @GetMapping(path = "/{id}", produces =
> "application/json;charset=UTF-8")

Answer (score 1):

It might be just a typo, you can try:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/{id}", produces =  "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
```

Comment: How about adding `spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8`, `spring.http.encoding.enabled=true` and `spring.http.encoding.force=true` to your `application.properties` ?

Comment: Another thing that came to my mind, how do you test this? Browser or POSTMAN? Maybe your browser encoding is not set to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Run the app with following arguments :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

or you can try setting in jvm level:

Add to config file (for application /var/app/app.jar it will be /var/app/app.conf) below line:

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
```

Comment: I'm running this locally. I tried setting "-Drun.jvmArguments="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" in VM options in Intellij. Also tried setting an environment variable export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'. Neither of the 2 worked.